# How to make marker with image and text for Map API v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

How to get customize markers with Imageview and Textview for google map v2 for android

Please refer to the attached image for better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view using XML

```
<FrameLayout 
     android:id="@+id/framelayout"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content">

     <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Get the view and set your values

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
```

Generate a bitmap

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

use this bitmap as your marker

```
Marker myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(0,0)
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mybitmap)));
```

Comment: Image and Texts can be dynamically updated inside from a fragment, I am new into this programming can you please elaborate?